# Translated module is always en-GB

Tags: module, joomla-3.4, language, translation

I'm writing a module for Joomla 3.4.3 and having issues with I18N.

My module directory structure:

```
+ mod_mymodname
  + tmpl
    - default.php
  + language
    + de-DE
      - de-DE.mod_mymodname.ini
      - de-DE.mod_mymodname.sys.ini
    + en-GB
      - en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini
      - en-GB.mod_mymodname.sys.ini
  - helper.php
  - mod_mymodname.php
  - mod_mymodname.xml
```

In my `mod_mymodname.xml`:

```
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>MOD_MYMODNAME_XML_NAME</name>
    <description>MOD_MYMODNAME_XML_DESC</description>
    <files>
        <filename>mod_mymodname.xml</filename>
        <filename module="mod_mymodname">mod_mymodname.php</filename>
        <filename>helper.php</filename>
        <folder>tmpl</folder>
        <folder>language</folder>
    </files>
    <languages folder="language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodname.sys.ini</language>
        <language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.mod_mymodname.ini</language>
        <language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.mod_mymodname.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="myfieldname"
                       type="integer"
                       default="5"
                       label="MOD_MYMODNAME_FIELD_MYFIELDNAME_LABEL"
                       description="MOD_MYMODNAME_FIELD_MYFIELDNAME_DESC"
                       first="1"
                       last="10"
                       step="1"/>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

In my `en-GB.mod_mymod.ini` (the `.sys.` ones are exactly the same):

```
MOD_MYMODNAME_XML_NAME="My Module Name"
MOD_MYMODNAME_XML_DESC="My Module Name is a sample module for Joomla! 3.x"
MOD_MYMODNAME_FIELD_MYFIELDNAME_LABEL="Set a number"
MOD_MYMODNAME_FIELD_MYFIELDNAME_DESC="My Module Name wants to have a number from you"
```

The `de-DE` version contains the German strings of course.

When I switch the complete Joomla system to `de-DE` (site, administrator, content) the administrative interface of Joomla is in German (as expected). Now I'm install (or even already have installed) my module via the extension installer (zip archive) and open the module settings. My module settings (config fields) are having the `en-GB` strings instead of the `de-DE` ones. The rest of the interface including the generic module settings are still in German.

What did I miss in order to create an I18N compatible Joomla 3.x module?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but your module definition/installation file should look more like this:

```
<extension type="module" version="3.1.0" client="site" method="upgrade">
    <name>mod_mymodname</name>
    <description>MOD_MYMODNAME_XML_DESC</description>
    <files>
        <folder>language</folder>
        <filename module="mod_mymodname">mod_mymodname.php</filename>
        <filename>mod_mymodname.xml</filename>
    </files>
    <languages folder="language">
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodname.ini</language>
        <language tag="en-GB">en-GB/en-GB.mod_mymodname.sys.ini</language>
        <language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.mod_mymodname.ini</language>
        <language tag="de-DE">de-DE/de-DE.mod_mymodname.sys.ini</language>
    </languages>
    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                <field name="myfieldname"
                       type="integer"
                       default="5"
                       label="MOD_MYMODNAME_FIELD_MYFIELDNAME_LABEL"
                       description="MOD_MYMODNAME_FIELD_MYFIELDNAME_DESC"
                       first="1"
                       last="10"
                       step="1"/>
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Here you can find full tutorial:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Introduction

Comment: I used that tutorial and sorry... I can't point any difference between your version an mine. Edit: I striped the most out of the manifest to have a minimal example. Now I see you have the module itself with files. I also do have it among other files in my original manifest.

Comment: So add correct XML file and file structure to your question. Cause what you added in your question doesn't make sense. In file structure you added `mod_mymodname` but in xml file you have `mod_mymodname` , also you didn't declare module main file. You have to add all files of you module in XML declaration.

Comment: So I updated questions manifest

Comment: I created a module (administration module) using your markup. Only created mod_mymodname.php file and language files. Here it is: http://www.filedropper.com/modmymodname_1 and it works like it should when I switch from Polish to English language. So it have to be something wrong with your files. Please add content of all your files.